# button onclick= returns var without slashes

Tags: javascript, php

The following code returns the $userurl, that is:

```
<button class="Urllink" type="button" onclick="window.parent.location.href=" www.facebook.com";"><img src="http://www.facebook.com/favicon.ico" width="16" height="16">Facebook</button>
```

CODE:

```
function userUrl($user){
    include ('bin/mysqllogin.php');
    $userUrl = '';
    $query = "SELECT * FROM urls WHERE Usernaam = '$user'";
    $result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
    if (!$result) {
        echo ' Query Failed ';
    }else{
        if (@mysqli_num_rows($result) >= 1) {
            while ($dbresult = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
                $userUrl .= '<p class="Link_par"><button class="Urllink" type="button" onclick="window.parent.location.href="';
                $userUrl .= $dbresult['Url'] . '";><img src=' . $dbresult["UrlIcon"] . ' width="16" height="16">' . $dbresult["UrlName"] . '</button>';
            }
        }
    }
    mysqli_close($dbc);
    return $userUrl;
}
```

As you all see $userUrl returns not the needed http://www.facebook.com. What am I doing wrong here?

Edit1: Found the solution. I needed to add /' around the var $dbresult['Url']. So the code changed to:

```
function userUrl($user){
    include ('bin/mysqllogin.php');
    $userUrl = '';
    $query = "SELECT * FROM urls WHERE Usernaam = '$user'";
    $result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
    if (!$result) {
        echo ' Query Failed ';
    }else{
        if (@mysqli_num_rows($result) >= 1) {
            while ($dbresult = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
                $userUrl .= '<p class="Link_par"><button class="Urllink" type="button" onclick="window.parent.location.href=\'';
                $userUrl .= $dbresult['Url'] . '\';"><img src=' . $dbresult["UrlIcon"] . ' width="16" height="16">' . $dbresult["UrlName"] . '</button>';
            }
        }
    }
    mysqli_close($dbc);
    return $userUrl;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to prepend `http://` to `$userUrl`. As such:

```
function userUrl($user) {
    include ('bin/mysqllogin.php');
    $userUrl = 'http://';    // <-- Prepended in here
    $query = "SELECT * FROM urls WHERE Usernaam = '$user'";
    $result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
    if (!$result) {
        echo ' Query Failed ';
    }else{
        if (@mysqli_num_rows($result) >= 1) {
            while ($dbresult = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
                $userUrl .= '<p class="Link_par"><button class="Urllink" type="button" onclick="window.parent.location.href="';
                $userUrl .= $dbresult['Url'] . '";><img src=' . $dbresult["UrlIcon"] . ' width="16" height="16">' . $dbresult["UrlName"] . '</button>';
            }
        }
    }
    mysqli_close($dbc);
    return $userUrl;
}
```

Please lookup SQL-injections by the way. Or, best choice, use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo).

Comment: Thanks @Erik for your quick response. I handled sql injection with the following code inside mysqllogin.php.
`$_POST = array_map("mysql_real_escape_string", $_POST);
$_GET = array_map("mysql_real_escape_string", $_GET);
$_REQUEST = array_map("mysql_real_escape_string", $_REQUEST);
$_COOKIE = array_map("mysql_real_escape_string", $_COOKIE);
$_SERVER = array_map("mysql_real_escape_string", $_SERVER); `

$dbresult['Url'] contains the string 'http://www.facebook.com' so why isn't that inserted into $userUrl?